# how to run a particular task on specific host in ansible

Tags: ansible

my inventory file's contents -

```
[webservers]
x.x.x.x ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu

[dbservers]
x.x.x.x ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

in my tasks file which is in common role i.e. it will run on both hosts but I want to run a following task on host webservers not in dbservers which is defined in inventory file

```
- name: Install required packages
  apt: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_items:
    - '{{ programs }}'
  become: yes
  tags: programs
```

is when module helpful or there is any other way? How could I do this ?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you want to run your role on all hosts but only a single task limited to the `webservers` group, then - like you already suggested - [`when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) is your friend.

You could define a condition like:

```
when: inventory_hostname in groups['webservers']
```

Comment: In case you have an application server and a database server, how your playbook, calling the role, will recognize wich tasks should be run on db server and witch ones on application server? Would  you put when statements on all included tasks ?

Comment: No, you would either have two separate playbooks or two plays with different hostgroups in the playbook.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you, this helps me too.

### hosts file:

```
[production]
host1.dns.name

[internal]
host2.dns.name
```

### requirements.yml file:

```
- name: install the sphinx-search rpm from a remote repo on x86_64 - internal host
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['internal']
  yum:
    name: http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.11-1.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
    state: present

- name: install the sphinx-search rpm from a remote repo on i386 - Production
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['production']
  yum:
    name: http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.11-2.rhel6.i386.rpm
    state: present
```

Comment: I am trying to do it in the same way but the task is skipping instead of running on another group of hosts

Comment: With a condition you can only limit the scope, not extend it. It will not run on a complete different set of hosts. The hosts have to be part of the current list of hosts of the play.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to consider in some scenarios is -

```
delegate_to: hostname
```

There is also this example form the ansible docs, to loop over a group. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html -

```
- hosts: app_servers

  tasks:
    - name: gather facts from db servers
      setup:
      delegate_to: "{{item}}"
      delegate_facts: True
      loop: "{{groups['dbservers']}}"
```